# Newly built computer is having problems running Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I have recently built my second computer on which I plan to use Ubuntu. The first computer I built runs Ubuntu very smoothly and I have not had any problems with it. I used the Startup Disk Creator on my first computer to create a USB drive to install Ubuntu on my new computer. This has all worked great, but the problem is that when I try to use this startup disk on my new computer it just immediately reboots. I select the option to install Ubuntu, but the farthest I can get is to the point where it wants me to select my timezone, and then it immediately reboots.

Does anyone know what a solution could be? I have tried to run the computer without installing Ubuntu, but it does the same thing. I don't know if the problem is with the hardware or software. The hardware I am using is:

```
CPU         : AMD A6-5400K 3.6GHz Dual-Core 
Motherboard : MSI A55M-E33 Micro ATX FM2+ 
Memory      : Kingston Fury White Series 4GB (1 x 4GB) DDR3-1866 
Storage     : Seagate Barracuda 160GB 3.5" 7200RPM Hard Drive
Case        : Cougar Spike MicroATX Mini Tower
Power Supply: EVGA 430W 80+ Certified ATX Power Supply
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit.

Comment: My instinct is that it has something to do with your memory. Make sure you've set it up correctly in your BIOS. That memory may not have been recognized correctly. Also run a memtest.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a hardware problem. Try to examine your memory with memtest: http://www.memtest.org/ - create a bootable pendrive, check voltages and temeratures in bios.

Answer (score 0):

I have examined my memory with both memtest86 and the memory test that works on the bootable ubuntu pendrive. There seem to be no problems with it. I can not see any problems with the temperatures in the BIOS.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation, you can use the comment function everywhere. You always can comment on your own posts.